# Can't Import java.awt.font Class

Tags: java, android, fonts

In an App I am working on, I would like to use the `java.awt.font` class. However, for some really strange reason I can't import it, so I get a `Font cannot be resolved to a type` error. I also tried manually adding the import statements for `java.awt.*` and `java.awt.font.*` but that doesn't help.

Did anybody experience a similar problem? Or does anybody know why I can't import `Font`?

Answer (score 3):

> However, for some really strange reason I can't import it

That is because `java.awt.Font` is not part of [the Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: Oh, I thought everything in Java was part of the Android SDK. Any ideas how I can still use it? Or is `android.renderscript.font` similar?

Comment: @Zero: "I thought everything in Java was part of the Android SDK" -- no. "Any ideas how I can still use it?" -- probably you can't. "Or is android.renderscript.font similar?" -- there is nothing by that name. You may wish to ask a separate StackOverflow question where you explain what you are trying to do, how you were thinking of doing it using `java.awt.Font`, and asking how to accomplish it using standard Android APIs.

Comment: @Zero Android TypeFace handles anything fonts i have used it before its amazing http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html

Comment: @Immanuel.I.George I can't use Typeface, because I need to be able to get font metrics as well

Comment: this perhaps http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.FontMetrics.html

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the Typeface, u can create a new Paint().  set its typeface, and then getFontMetrics().  but the FontMetrics isn't too helpful, the Paint it self can measureText, and getTextWidth and even calculate a Bounds right around the text.  I did use the font metrics to get the height of the font, cause i don't like my textbox's move the string up/down trying to center the string based on the actual height of the characters typed.  Strangly the total height of the font = -FontMetrics.top + FontMetrics.bot or bottom whatever it is.

I have been porting my Java Library for a few days now, and I was able to completely port all my String drawing/centering needs from java's font and fontmetrics,  to androids typeface and paint.